# How to concat two tables content together into one table in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

All:

Say I have table1 like:

```
name|id|email
```

And table2 is same structure, how can I concat their content together and make `select * from newbuildtable` query

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT * FROM table2);
```

or a common table expression:

```
WITH newbuildtable AS (
  SELECT * FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table2
)
SELECT * FROM newbuildtable;
```

or a view:

```
CREATE VIEW newbuildtable AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;

SELECT * FROM newbuildtable;
```

If you do not want to refer to the original data, copy all data into a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE newbuildtable AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;

SELECT * FROM newbuildtable;
```

Comment: Cos currently the number of data is small, it does not seems a problem. But I will test myself. BTW, how can I put multiple `WITH...AS` together, I try to built two concat tables and join them, but it always gives me syntax error